# Best way to setup Fstab to avoid system boot issues

Tags: boot, debian, grub

I have Linux system in which we force /dev/devname for running the system.

```
proc            /proc            proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/sda1       /                ext3    barrier=1,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda5       /opt             ext3    barrier=1,defaults        0       22 
/dev/sda2       /opt/vortex/dvss ext3    barrier=1,defaults 0   3
/dev/sda6       none             swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0    udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

We have this system running without issues till date. But, often in some installed machine we see that the system is not able to boot properly and sudden goes into  "Grub rescue"

When i mount the device as secondary and run E2Fsck i see that the system can be restored.

Now, we are trying to address this failure. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150741/fixing-system-boot-failure-due-to-grub-error]

In order, I noticed in some forums they say to SET UUID based boot up in FSTAB

what are all the advantages that we would have if it is set through UUID.

Is there a possibility that it would reduce my GRUB ERROR

Comment: The `/dev/sdXX` assignments will change around if you have more than one disk. Using UUID means that they will always point to the correct device / partition.

Comment: UUID won't change unless you format a volume, whereas dev name may change between reboots if they so desire. I don't know about grub errors, but using UUIDs will prevent boot stalls where the OS is waiting on a device that is not there to become active, and keeps your mounted volumes where you expect them (for instance if SDA2 mounted to /opt instead of /opt/vortex/dvss, you'd have some problems).

Comment: @jonah yes sure if i happen to connect multiple disk i see the possibility of /dev/sdX getting changed. But in my car it's single drive system. That is the reason why we freeze /dev/sda in Fstab

Comment: @Frank Thomas your point is accepted. But when i retrieve fdisk info its perfectly shows what i expect. So i see very little possibility of dev id getting changed.

Comment: Also, don't confuse UUID with the mount option setUID (suid/nosuid). suid can be a serious security risk if used improperly.